# How to write regex correctly so that it matches specific start digits?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that I want to expand so that it matches the start of a specific input.

right now my regex matches the following:
3 digits - 7 digits
and
3digits7digits(together)

I want to expand this by adding the following:

+46 (space) 073-4567891 (start with +46 followed by space, followed by 3 digiuts followed by 7 digits.

My attempt:

```
^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{10}$|^[+46]\s\d{3}-\d{7}$|^[+]\d{46}\s\d{10}$
```

I am using [this site](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) to check if the regex is correct but im not geting any matches.

what am i doing wrong here?

If anything is unclear just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work as you are using **[+46]**, which means choose **ANY** character from the brackets, so either modify your pattern or:

Use this one to capture mentioned string:

```
^\+46 \d{3}-\d{7}$
```

`\+` - First escape to get the 'plus' character,

`46` - then 46 explicit as they (probably) never change in your case,

- space to capture space,

`\d{3}-d{7}` - three digits follow by dash and seven digits.

Comment: ^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{10}$|^\+46\d{3}-\d{7}$ 
trtied that in combination with my code and i still dont get matches

Comment: @Ra3IDeN i think you've missed a **space** after **46**. So try this: `^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{10}$|^\+46 \d{3}-\d{7}$`

Comment: You are right! sorry been at this for a while. Thanks alot and thanks alot @Rawling for the detaild explenation.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN No problem, glad it works ; ) You can always upvote answers, even without marking them as accepted, so if you have found Rawlings answer helpful as well, upvote it please : )

Answer (score 4):

The following regex: `(\+46)? ?(\d{3})(-| )?(\d{6,7})`
captures this as input:

- +460764567891
- +46 076 567891
- +46 076567891
- +46 076-567891
- 0764567891
- 076 4567891

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `[+46]` matches "one +, 4 or 6 character", and `[+]\d{46}` matches "one + character, followed by 46 digits" - neither of which is what you want!

Replace both of these with either `[+]46` or `\+46`, both of which match "one + character followed by one 4 character and one 6 character". (Both `[ ]` and `\` are just alternate ways of escaping the + character.)

Comment: My test data: +460764567891 and new regex pattern after ur answer:
^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{10}$|^[+]46\d{3}-\d{7}$ 

I still dont get a match:(

Comment: @Ra3IDeN You've removed the 4th alternative - "with +46, without a hyphen". Your input also doesn't have a space after +46, which your question says it needs.

Comment: Actually it needs both, i just tested one to see if this would work cuz it would be easier for me to see manual errors. I ment no disrespect and im thankfull for the answer and the detaild explenation.